# R Create a new column from a header and reorder table using loop

Tags: r, loops, date, reorderlist

I would like to ask for help for extract informations from a header

I have a table with hundreds of rows and 1000 columns (equal) in a file (example below) like this one and I would like to make a loop to extract the dates from a header part (new column) and reorder the values in rows.

```
R2n_19970919__105056604_2_BF.MER_A123_DAY_00.nc <- c(0.09,0.09,0.08,0.08,0.06,0.07,0.09,0.08,0.08,"NA")
R2n_19970920__105056604_2_BF.MER_A123_DAY_00.nc <- c(0.08,0.08,0.08,0.07,"NA",0.05,0.08,0.08,0.08,"NA")
R2n_19970921__105056604_2_BF.MER_A123_DAY_00.nc <- c(0.07,"NA",0.08,"NA","NA",0.07,0.06,"NA",0.08,"NA")
data <- data.frame(R2n_19970919__105056604_2_BF.MER_A123_DAY_00.nc,R2n_19970920__105056604_2_BF.MER_A123_DAY_00.nc,R2n_19970921__105056604_2_BF.MER_A123_DAY_00.nc)
```

how to do that best? Help would be much appreciated.

Here is my expected result:

R2n_**19970919**__105056604_2_BF.MER_A123_DAY_00.nc = 1997/09/19.

```
Date        R2n.nc        
1997/09/19  0.09        
1997/09/19  0.09
1997/09/19  0.08
1997/09/19  0.08
1997/09/19  0.06
1997/09/19  0.07
1997/09/19  0.09
1997/09/19  0.08
1997/09/19  0.08
1997/09/19  NA
1999/09/20  0.08        
1999/09/20  0.08
1999/09/20  0.08
1999/09/20  0.07
1999/09/20  NA
1999/09/20  0.05
1999/09/20  0.08
1999/09/20  0.08
1999/09/20  0.08
1999/09/20  NA
2001/09/21  ...
.
.
.
```

Comment: Reshape data into long format,  extract the date part and coerce it to `as.Date`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik You are suggesting to change the title and description?

Comment: No he is suggesting a solution. Look at `?reshape`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Sotos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, using tips suggested by @Roman Luštrik :

```
library(stringr) # str_sub() function
library(reshape2) # melt() function

# Modify columns names (if date information is always at the same position)
names(data) = paste0(str_sub(names(data), 5,8), "-", str_sub(names(data), 9,10), "-",str_sub(names(data), 11, 12))
data$id = seq(1,nrow(data))

# Melt the data
data_melt = melt(data, id = "id")
```

```
> data_melt
   id   variable value
1   1 1997-09-19  0.09
2   2 1997-09-19  0.09
3   3 1997-09-19  0.08
4   4 1997-09-19  0.08
5   5 1997-09-19  0.06
...
```

Comment: Perfect @bVa. Great solution. Thank you very much Roman and bVa!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(anytime)

df <- stack(data)
df$ind <- anydate(substr(df$ind, 5, 12))

head(df)
##    values        ind
## 1    0.09 1997-09-19
## 2    0.09 1997-09-19
## 3    0.08 1997-09-19
## 4    0.08 1997-09-19
## 5    0.06 1997-09-19
## 6    0.07 1997-09-19
```

Though I'd probably do:

```
library(anytime)
library(dplyr)

tbl_df(data) %>% 
  stack() %>% 
  mutate(ind=anydate(substr(ind, 5, 12)))
## # A tibble: 30 × 2
##    values        ind
##     <chr>     <date>
## 1    0.09 1997-09-19
## 2    0.09 1997-09-19
## 3    0.08 1997-09-19
## 4    0.08 1997-09-19
## 5    0.06 1997-09-19
## 6    0.07 1997-09-19
## 7    0.09 1997-09-19
## 8    0.08 1997-09-19
## 9    0.08 1997-09-19
## 10     NA 1997-09-19
## # ... with 20 more rows
```

instead.

Comment: Did not work @hrbrmstr. Error in stack.data.frame(x, ...) : no vector columns were selected

Comment: use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in the data frame creation.